# Dynamic href changing source from mysql

Tags: mysql, thymeleaf

Dynamic href changing source from mysql database

```
    <table>
    <tr th:each="c : ${contents}">
    <td><a href="#"  th:href="@{c.content}" onclick="loadSWF(this.href, 'flashcontent');
        return false;" >Click here </a></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

Above code is examble of thymeleaf spring...........

i want to load .swf file on each iteration,

**c.content** gives location of .swf file every run..!!
Chrome console gives me 500 error 
**GET localhost:8080/learnware/student/c.content 500 (Internal Server Error)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like your variable `@{c.content}` is not being parsed. I'm not familiar with Thymeleaf but Wikipedia seems to suggest that you should use `${c.content}` instead?

**UPDATE**

We figured out that the actual syntax for using a variable in href is `@{${c.content}}`

Comment: How about @(${c.content}), I'm reading the documentation to see if I can figure something out..

Comment: Could not parse as expression: "@(${c.content})"

Comment: Oops I meant @{${c.content}}